# User markdown inside SQL or vice-versa

Tags: html, markdown, hiveql, apache-zeppelin

I've a specific requirement where I'm trying an amalgamation of `%md` & `sql`. Either I can include full functionality of `md` inside `sql` or `sql` inside `md`.

Example:

md inside sql:

```
%md textA=${temp text='OptA','OptB'|'OptC'}
select * from tableA where ${textA}='conditionalText';
```

---

sql inside md:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>select * from tableA a</td>
<td>select * from tableB where a.colA='condition'</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Any idea whether this is even possible? I'm using zeppelin btw to perform this activity; however zeppelin doesn't contain zeppelin context so my approach of sharing variables across interpreters is limited.

Answer (score 0):

SQL is for storing, reading, querying data in a datastore. It does not know how to transform Markdown markup to HTML.

Markdown is a simple markup format that is used to transform plain text into HTML. It does not know how to connect to a database server and execute SQL queries.

You have to provide the code that:

1. connects to an SQL server and executes queries.
2. transforms Markdown to HTML.

You can certainly store Markdown using SQL, but once you fetch the Markdown, you need to transform it.

If you have SQL queries in your Markdown that you want to execute, you need to provide code that extracts the queries from the Markdown and executes them. You have not stated what you might do with the query results.